# Display image in Databricks notebook error

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working on creating a databricks notebook template with company logo. Using the below code to display image is throwing error.

***Code:***

```
%md
<img src ='/test/image/MyImage.jpg'>
```

***Error:***

```
HTTP ERROR 403: Invalid or missing CSRF token
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Try this `<div style="text-align: center; line-height: 0; padding-top: 9px;">
  <img src="/test/image/MyImage.jpg" alt="My Company" style="width: 600px; height: 163px">
</div>` When data lake storage path is given for the image source it doesn't work. But, when the image source is replaced with `http://mycompany.com/image/MyImage.jpg` http file path it works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You either need to store image somewhere, and refer to it as a full URL, for example, you can refer your company site.

Another way is to upload file to the `/FileStore` directory on DBFS, and then you can refer to it using the `/files/` URL, that is supported in both HTML and Markdown (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data/filestore.html#embed-static-images-in-notebooks)):

```
%md
![my_test_image](files/image.jpg)
```

You can upload image using [databricks-cli](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli.html), or via [UI](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#browse-dbfs-using-the-ui) (if you have DBFS File Browser enabled). (Another option is the DBFS REST API, but it's cumbersome)

Answer (score 1):

Databricks uses [Markdown language](https://www.markdownguide.org/). After uploading your file to Databricks notebook, you can simply use:

```
%md 
<img src="files/my/path/to/image.png" alt="drawing"  width="1000"/>
```

You can use other image properties (like width and height) to adjust your image.